# To implement Windows Azure Service Bus in .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Tags: azureservicebus, asp.net-core-1.0, azure-servicebus-queues, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to use Azure Service Bus with .NET Core. When I try to install *WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 3.4.3* through *Nuget* package in my .Net Core App.

It gives me following error:

> Package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 3.4.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 3.4.3 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

Please suggest a compatible *Nuget* package of Windows Azure Service Bus for .Net Core App as I want to use "Queue Client" to send and receive message from Azure Service Bus.

Comment: There will be a new Service Bus .NET Standard client in the upcoming weeks. See the comments here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2016/11/14/service-bus-client-3-4-2-is-now-live/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure Service Bus with REST API. The url looks like:

```
http{s}://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queuePath|topicPath}/messages
```

And here you can find some examples: [Service Bus Runtime REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780762.aspx).

There is also an option to use AMQP protocol. There is [AMQP.Net Lite](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) Library which enables you that with some examples [here](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/tree/master/Examples/ServiceBus) and [here](https://carlos.mendible.com/2016/07/17/step-by-step-net-core-azure-service-bus-and-amqp/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget. And use the following code to push your messages.

```
IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString,entitypath);
Message message = new Message(utf8encodedstring);
await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
await queueClient.CloseAsync();
```